# Are these FKs necessary -- and are they stopping me?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, create-table

I'm having some difficulties with a database I'm creating for a summer camp, specifically with the PK and FK constraints. When I declare the FK constraint (e.g. FOREIGN KEY(PID) references Campers(CamperID)) I get an error running my code through pgAdmin (I'm using PostgreSQL). I understand that, for example, the Campers table is not yet created, and this is most likely part/all of the roadblock, however I feel like my FKs are still wrong somehow. To my understanding, a FK is a PK in another table -- but I feel like there is some redundancy or disconnect between my tables.

I've put the syntax for some of my CREATE statements below. I'm not sure if I'll get reprimanded for the quality of my (somewhat vague) question, but I feel a bit lost and would appreciate any help or advice. Thank you in advance!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS People;
CREATE TABLE People (
    PID                 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL            UNIQUE,
    FName               TEXT                NOT NULL,
    LName                   TEXT                NOT NULL,
    DOB                     DATE                NOT NULL,
    ArrivalDate     DATE                NOT NULL            DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    DepartureDate       DATE,               
    US_PhoneNum         VARCHAR(11)     NOT NULL,
    StreetAddress       VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL,
    Sex                 GENDER          NOT NULL,
    ZIP                 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(PID),
FOREIGN KEY(PID) REFERENCES Campers(CamperID),
FOREIGN KEY(PID) REFERENCES Counselors(CounselorID),
FOREIGN KEY(ZIP) REFERENCES Zip(ZIP)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Zip;
CREATE TABLE Zip (
    ZIP     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    City        TEXT                NOT NULL,
    State       VARCHAR(2)      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ZIP)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Campers;
CREATE TABLE Campers (
    CamperID        VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES People(PID),
    AgeGroup        AGES                NOT NULL,
    CabinID     VARCHAR(2)      NOT NULL,
    Bed         BEDTYPES            NOT NULL,
    GroupID     VARCHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CamperID),
    FOREIGN KEY(CamperID) REFERENCES People(PID),
    FOREIGN KEY(CabinID)  REFERENCES Cabins(CabinID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Bed)      REFERENCES Beds(Bed),
    FOREIGN KEY(GroupID)  REFERENCES Groups(GroupID)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counselors;
CREATE TABLE Counselors (
    CounselorID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES People(PID),
    GroupID         VARCHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
    CabinID         VARCHAR(2)      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CounselorID),
    FOREIGN KEY(GroupID) REFERENCES Groups(GroupID),
    FOREIGN KEY(CabinID) REFERENCES Cabins(CabinID)
);
```

ERROR message for further clarification:

```
ERROR:  relation "campers" does not exist
********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "campers" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

There are more tables (obviously) which I can provide the create statements for, if needed.

Comment: The `REFERENCES People(PID)` in `Campers` is the FK you want, not FOREIGN KEY(PID) REFERENCES Campers(CamperID)` in `people`. If you have a `REFERENCES` in the column definition then you don't need a separate `FOREIGN KEY` at the table level.

Comment: Great, I didn't know that! Thank you @muistooshort.

Comment: Which statement exactly throws that error?

Answer (score 0):

You should really start here: [Foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

> In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a field (or
>   collection of fields) in one table that uniquely identifies a row of
>   another table.

What you are trying to do in your script is to create a circular link between People, Campers and Counselors. Having a Primary Key field also a Foreign Key mandates that IDs across all referenced tables are identical.

... and to create a Foreign Key the referenced table must already exist in the database. So you should start with the table that does not have any Foreign Keys and create tables that reference only those tables created previously. Alternatively you can create all tables without Foreign Keys and add them later, when all the tables are present.

... and to answer the question, Foreign Keys are never necessary, but they might help.